# How can i find the ips in network in python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

How can i find the TCP ips in network with the range(i.e 132.32.0.3 to 132.32.0.44) through python programming and also want to know the which ips are alive and which are dead. please send me.. thanks for the repliers...

Comment: What is your relationship with this network? What is your relationship with the hosts on this network? Why do you want to know? How do you wish to define IP addresses as being "alive" or "dead"?

Comment: As MattH has said, we need more details before we can actually answer your question.

Comment: There is no such thing as "TCP ips in the network". A network has devices (usually computers), which have IP addresses.

If you want to check which IP addresses are associated with computers that are currently turned on, you can ping each IP address. Pinging assumes that each computer is configured to respond to echo requests, but this is usually the case. Ping doesn't involve TCP, by the way.

To discover TCP services on those computers, you have to first decide which TCP ports you want to test. If you want to check for web servers, you would usually try to connect to port 80.

Comment: or in short: You have to do everything nmap does.

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1 - "Finding IPs"**

Your example range, `132.32.0.3` to `132.32.0.44` doesn't match any subnet, which is curious.

Typically applications for checking whether hosts are up and down are normally scoped within a subnet, e.g. `192.168.0.0/28` (host addresses: `192.168.0.1` to `192.168.0.14`).

If you wanted to calculate the addresses within a subnet, I'd suggest you use [ipaddr](http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/). E.g.:

```
>>> from ipaddr import IPv4Address, IPNetwork
>>> for a in IPNetwork('192.168.0.0/28').iterhosts():
...   print a
...
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
192.168.0.6
192.168.0.7
192.168.0.8
192.168.0.9
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.12
192.168.0.13
192.168.0.14
```

However, if you're sure that you want an arbitrary range. You can convert an IPv4 address to an integer, increment and convert back to dotted IP. E.g.:

```
def aton(a):
  """
  Change dotted ip address to integer
  e.g. '192.168.0.1' -> 3232235521L
  """
  return reduce(lambda x,y: (x<<8) + y, [ int(x) for x in a.split('.') ])

def ntoa(n):
  """
  Change an integer to a dotted ip address.
  e.g. 3232235522L -> '192.168.0.2'
  """
  return "%d.%d.%d.%d" % (n >> 24,(n & 0xffffff) >> 16,(n & 0xffff) >> 8,(n & 0xff))

def arbitraryRange(a1,a2):
  """
  Generate all IP addresses between two addresses inclusively
  """
  n1, n2 = aton(a1), aton(a2)
  assert n1 < n2
  i = n1
  while i <= n2:
    yield ntoa(i)
    i += 1
```

Providing:

```
>>> for a in arbitraryRange('192.168.0.10','192.168.0.20'):
...   print a
...
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.12
192.168.0.13
192.168.0.14
192.168.0.15
192.168.0.16
192.168.0.17
192.168.0.18
192.168.0.19
192.168.0.20
```

---

**Part 2 - "Alive or Dead"**

The question of "alive" or "dead" is complex and entirely dependent on what you mean by those terms. To provide context and contrast, here's a list of testable qualities with regard to an IP address / host:

- Responds to ARP request?
- Responds to ICMP echo request?
- Responds to TCP SYN?