# how can i check the ipaddress ranges one to another in python networking

Tags: python, linux, sockets, ubuntu

how can I  find the addresses in python  if I have given any IP s range dynamically . I want the range of address from one to another ip and also count the ports which are connected  .If the  n number of IP s  connected

Comment: This is two separate questions. One of which appears in your other question, which I have answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291238/how-can-i-find-the-ips-in-network-in-python/6292841#6292841

Comment: Please spend a little time, read and absorb: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

To get all the ips combinations you can try to use the following code:

```
import itertools 

ips = itertools.product([193], [55,56], xrange(0,256), xrange(1, 256))
```

Comment: This isn't a generalised solution to "find all IPs between two IPs".

Comment: @MattH Sorry, was simply playing with itertools. I am not very familiar with the rules here. Should i remove my post?

Comment: @Artsiom: Generally no. Apparently incorrect answers may still provide useful information. You may receive down-votes for them though. There are many cases where the question is vague and/or ambiguous, which would reduce the chances of being down-voted. I'm just commenting that your proposed solution isn't general and wouldn't be applicable to many possible address ranges.

Comment: @Artsiom: I'm a little miffed because I provided a generalised solution to this part of the question yesterday in a duplicate by this author: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291238/how-can-i-find-the-ips-in-network-in-python/6292841#6292841

Comment: @MattH - oh, i see now. I am just a tester, so please bear with me since i am still have a lot to learn. Anyway i found strange for myself that quite a lot of pretty equal questions are asked by the same people again and again.

Comment: @Artsiom: Many cases of duplication are people blatantly wanting SO to do their homework / exam questions for them, which many SO users resist.

Comment: @MattH - ok, thanx for your help, i am always glad to know something new

Comment: @Artsiom: Welcome to SO, I hope you enjoy your stay! Talking about stackoverflow on stackoverflow is generally frowned upon, so I've been a little naughty in this comment thread. The FAQ is the best place to start and meta.stackoverflow.com is the best place to talk about stackoverflow.